# Combine elided and word wrap on qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a QLabel to show a text, and setting to word wrap property true, to show my text in lines when the size of the grid is smaller than the size of the text. But some words, when I define the minimum size to the grid, don't show all the letters.

Can I use Elided combined with word wrap property from QLabel?

Comment: Eliding text means you will be puposefully missing parts of the text to make it fit the available space. For example "this is my string" might become "this i....ing" or "this is my...". If this is fine for your application then you can certainly use this however it might be tricky to implement this in conjunction with QLabels lackluster word wrap implementation. I recommend implementing your own label class so you can perform all the calculations yourself!

Comment: Oh ok, I think now I understood the behavior of elided. Thanks, you helped me a lot!